ModuleNotFoundError: No module named, how come no model was named since it is written in the main code and in the model?
I created this model code but the django makemigrations command doesn't work and show an error.
The first code is where the database should be and where I put the name of the model I want, the second code is how the model is made so far and the last is the error that appears when I try to use makemigrations. I have no idea what to do to make it work.
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'livros'

from django.db import models

class Livros(models.Model):

nome = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
autor = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
co_autor = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
data_cadastro = models.DateField()
emprestado = models.BooleanField(default=False)
nome_emprestado = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
data_emprestimo = models.DateTimeField()
data_devolução = models.DateTimeField()
tempo_duração = models.DateField()

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, 
in _gcd_import   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, 
in _find_and_load   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1140,
in _find_and_load_unlocked ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'livros'`


the OG is quite confusing. I think you're missing the webapp.
within your virtual environment and at the command prompt, issue the following command:
python manage.py startapp livros

This will create your webapp livros adding a new directory (and several files.. including models.py) to your project. Next, we need to update your settings.py to allow django to know that your webapp, livros, exists.
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'livros',
]

Within the livros directory created with the startapp command, edit your models.py with the following code:
from django.db import models

class Livros(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    autor = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    co_autor = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    data_cadastro = models.DateField()
    emprestado = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    nome_emprestado = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    data_emprestimo = models.DateTimeField()
    data_devolução = models.DateTimeField()
    tempo_duração = models.DateField()

This should be sufficient to have your makemigrations generate instructions for the Livros table.
python manage.py makemigrations

If it doesn't see your livros updates, try the following:
python manage.py makemigrations livros

To actually apply these changes to the database, run your migrate command
python manage.py mirgrate

Within the views.py in the livros directory, add the following to access your model within your code
from .models import Livros

